# WebService Rest

Tags: web-service, post, jersey

Estou querendo saber como faço para enviar um `post` no formato `json`
usando um `form`.

Esse é o `form` que eu uso:

```html
<form action="rest/carros"  enctype='application/json' accept-charset="utf-8" method="post">
  <input name='carro[descricacao]' value='carro de form'/>
  <input name='carro[nome]' value='citroen'/>
  <input name='carro[tipo]' value='4-portas'/>
  <input name='carro[urlFoto]' value='www.foto'/>
  <input name='carro[urlVideo]' value='www.video'/>
  <input type="submit" value='enviar'/>
</form>
```

Esse o método que recebe o `post`:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + "; charset=utf-8")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + "; charset=utf-8")
public String salvarCarro(Carro c){
        business.salvarCarro(c);
        return "salvo";
}
```

Tudo está funcionando normal, já testei com o `postman` e quando eu envio um objeto assim :

```
{"carro":
        {
         "descricao":"um carro",
         "nome":"fiat",
         "tipo":"3-portas",
         "urlFoto":"www.foto",
         "urlVideo":"ww.video"
        }
}
```

Ele aceita perfeitamente, mas quando faço o `post` usando `form` apresenta:

> HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type

Não sei onde estou errando, ou se falta algum `jar` que faça a conversão em um objeto carro. Estou usando o `jersey`, só para lembrar.

Comment: Você tá mandando por ajax?

Comment: não, estou apenas fazendo desse jeito, o jersey deveria pegar esse post e criar o objeto. mas minha duvida é se so com isso da certo ou vou ter de fazer como alguns exemplos que eu vi que era com ajax usando jquery.           abrss

Answer (score 0):

Adicione @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA), para que o jersey saiba que ele poderá receber informações no formato de um formulário.
Da uma olhada nesse tópico [multiple-types-of-data-file-and-json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27643558/java-rest-jersey-posting-multiple-types-of-data-file-and-json)